# How to change the setTimeout() counter using an ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I wrote a small jQuery code that will display a dialog box if the page is not refreshed for 1800 seconds. The dialog has a countdown before the session automatically ends. If the user click "Yes, Keep working" then the counter resets and the dialog disappears. Otherwise the user is transferred to the logout page.

The issue that I am having here is when a user opens a new browser's tab and continue working on the new tab. Then the old tab will become idle "after 1800 seconds with no refresh" so they loose all their sessions and get logged out.

I have created a PHP page that will return how many seconds remaining by checking the time in the database using `$_SESSION` information. But I am not sure how I can reset the counter of when the dialog opens up.

I am not sure how can I modify my code to check the actual seconds remaining before the dialog box is displayed.

Here is my code

```
<!-- This script will alert a user before forcing to logout -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timer;
    var closeDialogAfter = 180;  //The default counter value
    var idleTimeOutLimit = 1800 - closeDialogAfter; //Display the dialog after @idleTimeOutLimit seconds of idle time
    var signOutScript = '/index.php?action=logout';   //logout url
    var keepAliveScript = '/ajax/handler-keep-me-alive.php';  //php page to handle ajax request to keep the session alive
    var dialogCountdown = '#dialog-countdown';  // the lable that is used to display the counter
    var idleTimeout= '#idleTimeout';  //the div that is used for the dialog 

    $(function(){

        //start the idle time out counter
        startTimeoutCounter();

        $( idleTimeout ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            open: function(){
                updateTimeoutCounter();
            },
            buttons: {
                "Yes, Keep working": function(e) {
                    $.ajax({    
                        url: keepAliveScript,       
                        success: function(data) {
                            startTimeoutCounter();
                            $( idleTimeout ).dialog("close");
                        }
                    });
                },
                "No, End Session": function(e){
                    forceLogOut();
                    $(this).dialog('close');                
                }
            }
        }); 
    });


    function startTimeoutCounter(){
        timer = closeDialogAfter;
        $(dialogCountdown).text(timer);

        setTimeout(function(){
            $( idleTimeout ).dialog("open");
        }, idleTimeOutLimit * 1000);
    }

    function updateTimeoutCounter(){

        if(  $( idleTimeout ).dialog( "isOpen" )){

            setTimeout(function(){
                timer = timer -1;
                $(dialogCountdown).text(timer);
                (timer < 2) ? forceLogOut() :   updateTimeoutCounter();
            }, 1000);
        } else 
            $(dialogCountdown).text(closeDialogAfter)
    }   

    function forceLogOut(){
        window.location = signOutScript;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Try using localstorage to set the remaining time across the tabs

Comment: @juvian How do I use local storage?

Comment: What do you mean by tabs?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 browser table or new instance of the browser.

Comment: That makes sense but needs clarifying in the question. My first interpretation was "tabs within a single page".

Answer (score 0):

in ur script php u need to return only the number of secondes left 
your javascript need to start with ajax request to the php page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get("timeleft.php",function(data){
        var timer;
        var closeDialogAfter = parseInt(data);  //<-- what i changed
        var idleTimeOutLimit = 1800 - closeDialogAfter; //Display the dialog after @idleTimeOutLimit seconds of idle time
        var signOutScript = '/index.php?action=logout';   //logout url
        var keepAliveScript = '/ajax/handler-keep-me-alive.php';  //php page to handle ajax request to keep the session alive
        var dialogCountdown = '#dialog-countdown';  // the lable that is used to display the counter
        var idleTimeout= '#idleTimeout';  //the div that is used for the dialog 

        $(function(){

            //start the idle time out counter
            startTimeoutCounter();

            $( idleTimeout ).dialog({
                resizable: false,
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 400,
                open: function(){
                    updateTimeoutCounter();
                },
                buttons: {
                    "Yes, Keep working": function(e) {
                        $.ajax({    
                            url: keepAliveScript,       
                            success: function(data) {
                                startTimeoutCounter();
                                $( idleTimeout ).dialog("close");
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    "No, End Session": function(e){
                        forceLogOut();
                        $(this).dialog('close');                
                    }
                }
            }); 
        });


        function startTimeoutCounter(){
            timer = closeDialogAfter;
            $(dialogCountdown).text(timer);

            setTimeout(function(){
                $( idleTimeout ).dialog("open");
            }, idleTimeOutLimit * 1000);
        }

        function updateTimeoutCounter(){

            if(  $( idleTimeout ).dialog( "isOpen" )){

                setTimeout(function(){
                    timer = timer -1;
                    $(dialogCountdown).text(timer);
                    (timer < 2) ? forceLogOut() :   updateTimeoutCounter();
                }, 1000);
            } else 
                $(dialogCountdown).text(closeDialogAfter)
        }   

        function forceLogOut(){
            window.location = signOutScript;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I think the code will read the current session only when the page is loaded. but what I need is to check the time before the dialog opens not when the page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you need is to check the time before the dialog opens. When the page loads, you can assume the full 1800 seconds.

I think you probably want something like this (see comments in code and notes below).

```
<!-- This script will alert a user before forcing to logout -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var timer;
    var closeDialogAfter = 180;  //The default counter value
    var idleTimeOutLimit = <?php echo $sessionTimeoutValue ?>; //Time after which 
    var signOutScript = '/index.php?action=logout';   //logout url
    var keepAliveScript = '/ajax/handler-keep-me-alive.php';  //php page to handle ajax request to keep the session alive
    var getSessionTimeScript = '/ajax/get_session_time.php';  //php page to handle ajax request for the remaining session length
    var $dialogCountdown = $('#dialog-countdown');  //the container used to display the counter
    var $idleTimeout = $('#idleTimeout'); //the div that is used for the dialog

    function startTimeoutCounter(t) {
        t = Math.max(closeDialogAfter, parseInt(t, 10) || 0);
        $idleTimeout.dialog("close");
        setTimeout(getSessionTimeRemaining, (t - closeDialogAfter) * 1000);
    }
    function updateTimeoutCounter() {
        if($idleTimeout.dialog("isOpen")) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                timer = timer - 1;
                $dialogCountdown.text(timer);
                if(timer < 2) {
                    // Here, forceLogOut() can't be assumed because 
                    // the session may have been kept alive from another tab.
                    // Therefore, call getSessionTimeRemaining().
                    getSessionTimeRemaining();
                } else {
                    updateTimeoutCounter();
                }
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            $dialogCountdown.text(closeDialogAfter);
        }
    }   
    function forceLogOut() {
        $idleTimeout.dialog("close");
        window.location = signOutScript;
    }
    function getSessionTimeRemaining() {
        $.get(getSessionTimeScript).then(function(t) {
            t = parseInt(t, 10) || 0;
            if(t <= 0) {
                forceLogOut();
            } else if(t <= closeDialogAfter) {
                timer = closeDialogAfter;
                $dialogCountdown.text(timer);
                $idleTimeout.dialog("open");
            } else {
                startTimeoutCounter(t);
            }
        }, function(error) {
            // Something went wrong, safest action is logout
            // This will only happen under abnormal circumstances
            console.error(error);
            forceLogOut();
        });
    };
    function keepAlive() {
        $.get(keepAliveScript).then(startTimeoutCounter);
    }

    $idleTimeout.dialog({
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        open: updateTimeoutCounter,
        buttons: {
            "Yes, Keep working": keepAlive,
            "No, End Session": forceLogOut
        }
    });
    // On page load, the session should have been reset by the script that serves this page,
    // therefore no need to call keepAlive(), though that would do the same job.
    startTimeoutCounter(idleTimeOutLimit);
});
</script>
```

You'll see the main structural difference is that `$(function() {...})` now wraps everything. This avoids the need to use the global name space.

The new fuction `getSessionTimeRemaining()` and its server-side counterpart `getSessionTimeScript` are central to allowing more than one tab to respond to the session timing out.

The two scripts `keepAliveScript` and `getSessionTimeScript` (which can be the same script with a different querystring) must both return time, `t`, in seconds. `t` is assummed to be a String, which is converted to Number with `parseInt()`. You may want to return a time slightly less than the actual session time remaining, thus allowing a short "period of grace". What you don't want is to give the user hope of keeping the session alive when it has already expired.

The function `startTimeoutCounter(t)` now accepts a time in seconds so it can work on whatever time remains, which will not necessarily be the full 1800 seconds, depending on whether the call comes (asynchronously) from `keepAlive()` or `getSessionTimeRemaining()`.

The new fuction `keepAlive()` allows for tidy 'buttons' definition.

All completely untested. You will probably still need to tinker around with it.